# ConcurrentLinkedQueue and list methods

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I'm at the moment looking to make a thread-safe program that allows me to implement a time-priority in my program.  I'm happy to share code with you if you'd like, but that's not really important to my question I don't think. I originally used a linked list when I was working on getting a (non-thread safe) version of this program up and running, but now that I'm switching to a thread-safe version, I've changed from a linked list to a concurrent linked queue.  The issue is that I need to get elements from the queue (usually from the head, occasionally from the tail).  I really just need to see if the element at the head satisfies a certain property.  In the linked list version it looked something like:

```
if (order.getQuantity()>= a.getFirst().getQuantity()){
                        Fill orderfill = new  Fill(a.getFirst().getQuantity(),a.getFirst().getLimitPrice(), order.getOrderID(),a.getFirst().getOrderID());
                        fills.add(orderfill);
                        order.setQuantity(order.getQuantity()-a.getFirst().getQuantity());
                        a.removeFirst();
```

where here "a" is my linked list.  When I change to concurrent linked queue, the getFirst method isn't there anymore.  Is there a method that is queue-friendly that accomplishes the same goals as the getFirst or getLast methods of linked list?  (As you can see, I only need to get the object so that I can start using methods relevant to that object for something else).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html), it offers `getFirst()` and `getLast()` methods.

Comment: Is that one thread safe?  I'm not seeing anything documentation-wise saying that it is.

Comment: It is there in the link: "Concurrent insertion, removal, and access operations execute safely across multiple threads."

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I didn't see that.  (Don't know how I missed it, it's right there at the beginning).

Comment: How does this add elements to the deque?  I was a bit quick to accept the answer and call it good, but one of the reasons I liked the linked list and queue approaches was that it was a first-in-first-out structure.  However, it doesn't seem like deque works that way (it allows for insertion at both ends)?  So if I want to use this approach, how to I maintain the first-in-first-out nature?  EDIT: Nevermind, this extends queue which is FIFO so I can just treat it as a queue and it's fine right?

Comment: @user1849003 exactly. You can treat it just like an ordinary queue, but sometimes "peeking" at the last element.

Comment: Follow-up: My java doesn't seem to want to use ConcurrentLinkedDeque.  When I look to import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque it just tells me there's an error.  Isn't this part of the standard java library?  If yes, why is it not working for me?  If no, do I have to manually implement this? EDIT: Nevermind, the answer is that I was using JRE6 and it's included in JRE7. I just downloaded JRE7 and it seems to work fine.